# travis-ci 401 - Bad credentials // See: https://developer.github.com/v3 (Octokit::Unauthorized)

Tags: travis-ci

I created a GitHub personal access token with `repo`, `read:repo_hook`, and `user:email` scopes, then encrypted the token with `travis encrypt`, then pasted that string into my `.travis.yml` file in the deploy block, but when I tag a release, my job fails with:

```
Installing deploy dependencies
/home/travis/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.5/gems/octokit-4.6.2/lib/octokit/response/raise_error.rb:16:in `on_complete': GET https://api.github.com/user: 401 - Bad credentials // See: https://developer.github.com/v3 (Octokit::Unauthorized)
```

I know the encrypted string works, because it does successfully upload the files to my release tag and the github logs show that the key was accessed this week, but I can't figure out why this error is happening.

Here is a link to the build: https://travis-ci.com/github/benkonz/gameboy_emulator/jobs/331211965

Here is a link to the repo: https://github.com/benkonz/gameboy_emulator

Answer (score 0):

i have the same issues,
the reason is my `$GITHUB_TOKEN`is set in travis settings.

but my `.travis.yml` is set in secure mode.

```
deploy: 
  ...
  api_key: 
    secure: $GITHUB_TOKEN
...
```

so , i change my .travis.yml

```
deploy:
   ...
  api_key: $GITHUB_TOKEN

....
```

sloved my problem.